# Do something when an activity loads 'N' times in android

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am developing an android app and I want it to do a particular action(say for example, go to a particular URL) when the user loads it for 'N' times. How do I go about doing it. I know its got to do with SharedPrefs and Activity LifeCycle but I am not being able to get a headstart into it. Can someone plz suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onCreate method in your activity to set a counter in SharedPrefs. Increase it by 1 each time and when it reaches N, do your thing..

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int count = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);
if (count == N) {
  ...
} else {
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putInt("count", count + 1);
  editor.commit();
```

}